# Xtick labels won't rotate?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am not able to get my x tick labels to rotate, currently they overal

I have tried (shown in code, to use the rotation argument, I have tried working with plt.setp and trying to rotate within the first plot argument. If i only have one axis then It plots perfectly, it's the secondary axis that causes the issue for some reason

```
df_summary['AV_PRICE'] = np.random.randint(30, 150, size=len(df_summary))
plt.figure
df_summary.plot(kind='bar',x='BMCODE_type',y = 'AV_DURATION',xticks=[])
df_summary['AV_PRICE'].plot(secondary_y=True, 
legend='TRUE',style='g',ax=None, mark_right=False,xticks=[])
loc = range(len(df_summary))
plt.xticks(loc,df_summary['BMCODE_type'],rotation='vertical')
```

I would like the labels to be vertical rather than horizontal, any ideas would be great!

Comment: `plt.xticks` acts on the currently active axes. This would be the secondary axes. But the secondary axes has no x ticks shown. If you use `ax = df.plot(...)` you have a handle of the axes to use for doing all kinds of modifications you need.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. How would that work if my df.plot is plotting an x and y value like in this case?

Comment: Feel free to provide a [mcve] that I could correct.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest could you further explain how to use `ax = df.plot()` to modify the xticks?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's 8 months too late, but...

Use the `rot` argument when plotting the secondary axis and set it to 90:

```py
df_summary['AV_PRICE'].plot(secondary_y=True, legend='TRUE', style='g',
                            ax=None, mark_right=False,xticks=[], rot=90)
```